# Two divs with fixed widths need equidistant spacing in a parent div

Tags: css, html

I have two divs (which have a fixed width of 150px) within another parent div, which has a changing width, depending on the browser width.

I would like to position the two child divs within the parent, so the margin between the two divs would be equal to the margins between the edges of the parent div and child divs.

Example with red arrows always having equal lenghts:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: you could do what I first suggested, but now add

```
#leftwrapper, #rightwrapper { text-align: center; }
#childdiv1, #childdiv2 { display: inline-block; }
```

inline-block, instead of block, and you don't need the margins then for child div...

if that don't work, which probably won't, it might be VERY hard to get what you want to happen without using a table

you would have to create two new div wrappers

so you have

```
#parentdiv { display: block; width: 100%; }
#leftwrapper { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
#rightwrapper { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
#childdiv1 { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
#childdiv2 { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

html would be like

```
<div id="parentdiv">
    <div id="leftwrapper">
        <div id="childdiv1">your stuff</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightwrapper">
        <div id="childdiv2">your stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but this results in the middle space being larger than those on the sides, I need all spaces equal.

Comment: yeah, that doesnt work, because that also messes up the text within the two child divs.

Comment: could you please suggest on how to use a table in this case? Thank you =)